# BeautifulSoup get only content text

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Im new to python and BeautifulSoap. And I implement my scraper like that:

```
title_attr = soup.find("meta", {"name": "description"})
```

And print(title_attr) is like that:

```
<meta content="I want to only this text. How can I make this?" name="description"/>
```

But I want to get only content text.
How can I make this?

Comment: title_attr["content"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include .text at the end of the find expression.